# Is it possible to have a meta tag for theme-color with content being a CSS variable?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, meta-tags, css-variables

I've got a WordPress child theme that I'd like to adjust the theme-color meta tag for, but I'd like to be able to change it via the GUI in future rather than jumping back into functions.php (and I don't want to use a plugin).

Is there a way to use a CSS variable that lives in an external stylesheet as the color set for the meta tag?

I've tried it but it doesn't seem to be working, even with the stylesheet being linked before the meta line.

Here's the code:

```
function add_meta_tags() {
// All pages
    // Theme colors
    // Chrome, Firefox OS, and Opera
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="var(--wp--preset--color--contrast)">';
    // Chrome, Firefox OS, and Opera - Blogger
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="var(--wp--preset--color--contrast)">';
    // Windows Phone
    echo '<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="var(--wp--preset--color--contrast)">';
    // Windows Phone - Blogger
    echo '<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="var(--wp--preset--color--contrast)">';
    // iOS Safari
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">';
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">';
    // iOS Safari - Blogger
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">';
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
```

Comment: Everything is logical. HTML (from which the meta tag syntax comes) knows nothing about CSS variables. And especially PHP has no idea about them.

To solve your question, you need to go to the file in PHP where you store the --wp--preset--color--contrast value and insert it into the template as a PHP variable.

Another solution is to insert the desired meta tag using JS, but you need the CSS to be loaded first with your CSS variables. Then you can add the desired meta tag.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov ah I get what you're saying, that makes total sense. I might try to make a javascript function to grab the CSS variable from the stylesheet and replace the colors in the meta tags.

Thanks mate!